# jQuery: How to know the item is dropped in sortable ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to know where the item is being drop. for example, if "item1" is drop on the 1st box then it will be listed on the box above and if "item1" which is now on the current box1 and drag and drop on the other boxes then the list item on the box above will be transfer to the other box which is the item1 is currently listed. In other words, the list of items above depends on what items are listed below. I hope someone could help me to this

```js
$("ol").sortable({
    connectWith: "ol",
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.text());
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
.drop1,.drop2,.drop3{
    background-image:url(http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-04-at-7.00.35-am.png);
    background-size:64px 64px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td{
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td{
    padding-top:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
td{
    text-align:center;
}
div {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#777;
}
li:active {
    cursor:move;
}
ol {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
}
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Box1</td>
        <td>Box2</td>
        <td>Box3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="drop1">
                <ol></ol>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="drop2">
                <ol>
                    <li>item1</li>
                    <li>item2</li>
                    <li>item3</li>
                    <li>item4</li>
                    <li>item5</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="drop3">
                <ol></ol>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use `event.target` to get the `ol` for the dropped `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing last character of `ui.item` parent `class` as selector for "Box1", "Box2", "Box3"

```js
$("ol").sortable({
    connectWith: "ol",
    receive: function (event, ui) {
      // filter `ui.item` parent ,
      // `.slice()` last charater of `ui.item` parent `class`
      var filter = ui.item.closest("[class^=drop]").attr("class").slice(-1);
      // "boxes" , "Box1", "Box2", "Box3"
      var tr = $("table tr:eq(1) td");
      // append `ui.item.text()` to filtered "box"
      tr.eq(filter - 1).append("<br />"+ui.item.text());
      // remove `<br>``ui.item.text()` from previous "box"
      tr.not(tr.eq(filter - 1)).html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(new RegExp("<br>"+"+"+ui.item.text()), "");
      });    
    }
}).disableSelection()
// at `.sortable()` initialization , 
// append `ol li.ui-sortable-handle` `html`
// to filtered "box":"Box2"
.each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).children().html(function(i, html) {
    $("table tr:eq(1) td").eq(
      $(el).parent("[class^=drop]").attr("class").slice(-1) - 1
    ).append("<br>"+html)
  });
});
```

```css
.drop1,.drop2,.drop3{
    background-image:url(http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-04-at-7.00.35-am.png);
    background-size:64px 64px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td{
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td{
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) td{
    padding-top:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
td{
    text-align:center;
}
div {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#777;
}
li:active {
    cursor:move;
}
ol {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
}
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Box1</td>
        <td>Box2</td>
        <td>Box3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="drop1">
                <ol></ol>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="drop2">
                <ol>
                    <li>item1</li>
                    <li>item2</li>
                    <li>item3</li>
                    <li>item4</li>
                    <li>item5</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="drop3">
                <ol></ol>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```